# DevTools error when using Selenium Chromedriver with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to initialize a ChromeDriver with selenium (win-64) for doing some scraping task. This is the initialization code to create the object.

```
class ChromeDriver:
    def __init__(self,dataset_path):
        """
        Function to initialize the Chromedriver
        """
        try:
            service = Service("path/to/chromedriver.exe")
            chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
            chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
            chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
            chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-tools")
            chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
            chrome_options.add_argument("--no-zygote")
            chrome_options.add_argument("--single-process")
            chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=2560x1440")
            chrome_options.binary_location = "path/to/chromium"
            chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome-user-data")
            chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9295")
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=chrome_options)
            self.dataset = dataset_path #Irrelevant for my problem, this is for third purpose
     
            if self.driver:
                print('Started Chrome Driver')
                self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
                self.driver.set_script_timeout(30)
            else:
                print('failed to start Chrome Driver')

        except WebDriverException as ex:
            print(f'Unexpected exception: {ex}\nTrace:{traceback.format_exc()}')
```

When I use it with another method for retrieving a webpage and screenshoting it, I get the following error:

```
Message: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome-headless-shell=120.0.6099.109)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF690272142+3514994]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68FE90CE2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68FD376AA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68FD20839]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68FD206EB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68FD1FF59]
And so on...
```

Both versions of chromedriver and chromium (normal, not headless shell one) are compatible to each other, and are updated, as you can see here https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/, I have the latest version of both of them. Tried changing the port, reinstalling chromedriver and chromium, deleting the headless option. Instead of referencing local paths for chromedriver tested introducing it in the PATH, but the result was pretty much the same.